# Change of GPS firmware Geoexplorer Trimble

Tags: trimble

Is it possible to install the firmware of a GPS of another brand, the Geoxplorer XH 2005 of Trimble?

Informative note: the Geoxplorer XH 2005 has Windows Mobile Operating System 5.1